# SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector for kafka returns an error ''must be a directory''

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am following the tutorial for moving data from csv to kafka provided in https://rmoff.net/2020/06/17/loading-csv-data-into-kafka/. My folder structure is similar to the one found here https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/csv-to-kafka.

[image]

However whenever I try to execute the connector

```
    curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
        -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-csv-spooldir-00/config \
        -d '{
            "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
            "topic": "orders_spooldir_00",
            "input.path": "/data/unprocessed",
            "finished.path": "/data/processed",
            "error.path": "/data/error",
            "input.file.pattern": ".*\\.csv",
            "schema.generation.enabled":"true",
            "csv.first.row.as.header":"true"
}'
```

I receive an error saying [image]

Could someone let me know what is happening? I have spent a few hours on this already

Comment: Do the directories `/data/unprocessed`, `/data/processed`, and `/data/error` exist on the machine running the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and then i realise that the directories must be a writable by the same user running the kafka connect.

If not , you will be always getting the above error.

[image]

Check the [official doc](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)